# Changing version of python when using nohup

Tags: python, python-2.7, nohup

I am trying to run a python program called compare.py with the linux nohup command which keeps the program running until it is done without interruption.  my python program has packages which can only run on python 2.7 and when i use nohup command program is run in python 2.6.  how do i change the version of python when using nohup?

Example: nohup python compare.py $

I tried doing: 
alias python=python2.7

before starting program and version of python isn't switched.  how do i switch the version of python to 2.7 when i run nohup?

Comment: try: 'nohup python 2.7' . Also what do you get if you type 'which python'?

Comment: i can replicate your issue; i think this is because your alias isn't applied because you don't start the command with python

Comment: Is it possible your `PATH` variable isn't `export`ed, so only direct launches are using it for lookup? If so, only the default executable search locations would be checked by any command invoked by `nohup`, while the full `PATH` would be checked when you directly invoke `python` at the command line. If that's the case, running `export PATH`, then retrying your `nohup` command should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a shebang line to specify the interpretter. At the start of your Python file, put something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# This should be a path to an interpreter that you know for sure is Python 2.7
```

Then, use `chmod +x file.py` to make the Python file itself executable, and omit the `python` part of your nohup command, eg. `nohup ./compare.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with anaconda python. While using nohup python, it was using python 2.7 but generic python command in terminal was taking me to 3.6.

```
nohup ~/anaconda3/bin/python scriptname.py
```

Providing full path to python after nohup command will solve the issue